# how to have arraylist in grails domain class

Tags: grails

I am new to grails. I have the following requirement, how to achieve it ?

```
class File {
    list<Employee> listOfCaseWorkersWhoHaveWorkedOnThisFile;  <<<---- how to achieve this ? 

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Employee {
    list<File> filesOwnedByHim <<<<<-------- also this ?

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

My requirement is that a `File` will have a list of `Employee`s with zero or more elements and same for `Employee`.
Do I have to implement one of the GORM (one-to-one, one-to-many etc) here ? If yes how ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hasMany` which is one-to-many association between your classes.

```
class File {
    static hasMany = [employees: Employee]

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Employee {
    static hasMany = [files: File]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Then you can easily use GORM operations on it (addTo,findBy,etc).

Ref: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html